# Has anybody ever used QaasWall to prevent brute force attacks?

Tags: sql, brute-force, windows-firewall

We suffered a brute force attempt on our SQL database yesterday and obviously want to prevent this from happening again. The bot or whatever it was was trying to log into the sa account about 30 times a second so in the first instance we have changed the sa account and restricted the IP range that can access SQL via windows firewall. We are also considering disabling the sql server browser and changing the default port.

The problem is none of these things will prevent malicious log in attempts.

I came across a piece of open source software called QaasWall and wondered if anybody had used it and whether it is reputable.
Here is a link to the project site: http://sourceforge.net/projects/qaaswall-window/

Any other tips on how to restrict the number of server log in attempts would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.
Clayton.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is completely disabling access to the database from all hosts which do not need it. E.g. by binding to `localhost` if the DB is only accessed locally or blocking any connections to the IP/port used by the DB in your firewall.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. What we were going to do was disable the sql browser agent that we used to modify the database ourselves, but I think we will do as you suggest and block at the firewall level but leave an exception for our specific IP. What we really want to do is create a dynamic blacklist of IPs so that if more than n connections are attempted per second that the IP it came from is automatically blacklisted. Does anybody know how we would set that up? Is that something that can be configured in Windows Firewall?

Comment: **Why** do you need to open the database to the public internet?

Comment: Hi. Well we don't actually need to and have now blocked access (by disabling all access apart from the localhost), but it doesn't seem to have stopped this particular attack. If I'm honest I am a little ignorant I'm afraid. I'm not entirely sure how this attacker has found our database.

Comment: Probably it's a worm trying to attack it. There was some SQL Server worm some years ago and maybe it's still trying to infect systems. However, if all external access is blocked and there are still attacks it means they are coming from an internal IP (or the whitelist does not work)

Answer (score 0):

TheifMaster is correct...the SQL Slammer was really vicious, but installing SQL Server SP3 or SP4 fixed the vulnerability in the sql server listner that this worm exploited.  When you install SQL Server 2000 Pre-SP3 from disk your server will get pinged to death...this is why I disable the network connections while installing SQL Server until I can get it fully updated.

I recently installed QAAS Wall on one of my W2003 Servers and it works, but I'm having some difficulties getting the whitelist to work property.  It keeps blocking access from one of my database servers.